# grails: marking field transient when domain class is a persistence annotated POJO

Tags: persistence, pojo, grails-2.0

I have a persistence annotated POJO for a domain class and all works great, but I can'f figure out how to make one of the fields transient. The examples I've seen and the field to transients right in the class. Can this be done in the controller instead? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to make a field transient in a controller rather than inside the domain object itself?

Comment: I don't have 'native' grails domain object, only a Java class with persistence annotations. I figured out where to add constraints to that, but I'm little stumped by handling the transiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to annotate the field in POJO itself:

```
@Transient
String someString;
// getters, setters, etc. omitted for brevity
```